# Why can't I iterate over this queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to use a basic for loop to iterate over this query and it is giving me a "Company is not iterable" error. Any help?

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token, pk):
try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    company = Company.objects.get(pk=uid)
except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, Company.DoesNotExist):
    company = None
if company is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(company, token):
    pmm_date = Thursday.objects.get(pk=pk)
    company.is_registered = True
    company.save()
    pmm_date.assigned_company = company
    pmm_date.save()

    automatic_denial_list = Company.objects.exclude(company).filter(pmm_date=pmm_date)
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    for company in automatic_denial_list:
        if company.email_one or company.email_two:
            mail_subject = 'Denied Pizza My Mind Visit'
            message = render_to_string('thursdays/denied_visit.html', {
                'user': company.name,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
            })
            to_email = company.email_one if company.email_one else company.email_two
            email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            # company.delete()
    return redirect('/')
else:
    return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

The error is when I define automatic_denial_list. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So when you are using exclude you have to do a field lookup. Try this:

```
automatic_denial_list = Company.objects.exclude(id=company.id).filter(pmm_date=pmm_date)
```

This is assuming your primary key is id, which is the default in django

Info on field lookups is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Comment: Why is that any different than me simply putting “company” inside exclude()?

Comment: Because of how exclude works. It needs a field in the database and a value of that field to exclude. Or some other field lookup described in that link

Comment: Fixed it! Had to add exclude to the end of the query statement